# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.game

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following error staring me in the face.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.game_04BC2EA428E3397C72CED2755A5A78B93F676BBC970F6B9A8635AD53B08FEBCB', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TeamBuildingCompetition.ViewModels.EditGameVM'

I have an ASP.NET NVC 5 intranet application. I created an edit view  from a view model to update contents of my database. Content of the database in question is an html content which was posted in by a rich text editor. When I load the edit view, it shows the above error.

Below is my edit view:

```
@model TeamBuildingCompetition.ViewModels.EditGameVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_new.cshtml";
}
<script>
    tinymce.init({ selector: '#description' });
    tinymce.init({ selector: '#gameRule' });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Game", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <section id="middle">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="center"><h1>Edit Games </h1></div>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.gameID)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gameName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.gameName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gameName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gameRule, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.gameRule, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gameRule, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gamePicture, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.gamePicture, new { @type = "file", @name = "gamePicture" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Below is the View Model for the Edit View:

```
namespace TeamBuildingCompetition.ViewModels
{
    public class EditGameVM
    {
        public int gameID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Game Name")]
        public string gameName { get; set; }

        [Required][AllowHtml]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]        
        public string description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [AllowHtml]
        [Display(Name = "Game Rules")]
        public string gameRule { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Game Picture")]        
        public string gamePicture { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally, here's the controller to do the update:

```
    public ActionResult Update(EditGameVM model)
    {
        try { 
        game objGame = new game
        {
            gameID = model.gameID,
            gameName = model.gameName,
            description = model.description,
            gameRule = model.gameRule,
            gamePicture = model.gamePicture.ToString()
        };            
            objBs.gameBs.Update(objGame);
            TempData["Msg"] = "Created Successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("Edit");
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Entity:'{0}' Property: '{1}' Error: '{2}'",
                    validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                    validationError.PropertyName,
                    validationError.ErrorMessage));
                }
            }
            //throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed saving data: '{0}'", sb.ToString()), dbEx);

            TempData["Msg"] = sb.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit");
        }
    }
```

Here's my Get Method:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0) 
    {
        if (id == 0)
        {
            id = 1;
        }
        var gameList = objBs.gameBs.GetByID(id);
        return View(gameList);
    }
```

I will appreciate all effort to resolving this.

Comment: The message is self explanatory - your not passing the correct model to the view. But you have not shown your GET method which is what generates the error.

Comment: I have include the Get method in my question

Comment: `objBs.gameBs.GetByID(id)` does not return a model which is typeof `EditGameVM`, hence the exception. You need to initialize and instance of `EditGameVM`, set its properties based on `gameList` and then return the view model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: This is what I did and it worked
        public ActionResult Edit(EditGameVM model, int id = 0) 
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                id = 1;
            }
            var gameList = objBs.gameBs.GetByID(id);
            model = new EditGameVM
            {
                gameID = id,
                gameName = gameList.gameName,
                gamePicture = gameList.gamePicture,
                gameRule = gameList.gameRule,
                description = gameList.description
            };
            return View(model);
        }

Comment: Remove the `EditGameVM model` parameter from your GET method (awful practice)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Done! however, the edited post isn't reflected in the database.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but it seems to be a different issue, so ask a new question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: It's a different issue which has been posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33777965/updates-not-reflecting-in-database-from-my-edit-view

Answer (score 1):

You do not send your model to view, so you caught an error. It is possible to do by this way:

As you use some temporary storage mechanisom like TempData

```
TempData["Msg"] = objGame;
return RedirectToAction("Edit");
```

Then just read it in your **GET** `Action` method again of your `View`.

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{  
   //Here you should cast your TempData to EditGameVM:    
   EditGameVM receivedModel=TempData["Msg"] as EditGameVM;

   //To take data from TempData["Msg"], you should use receivedModel object:
   string gameID=receivedModel.gameID;
   string gameName=receivedModel.gameName;
   return View(receivedModel);
}
```

`TempData` uses `Session` object behind the scene to store the data. **But once the data is read the data is terminated.**

Comment: Why would I need to use TempData["Msg"] = sb.ToString(); ?
Then how will I get the ID of the game to the view using this approach? I can't see where id is passed in from the ActionResult?

Answer (score 1):

I failed to pass the model to my view hence, the above error. After careful examination of my code, I did the following according to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke advice. All credit goes to this great guy.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0) 
    {
        if (id == 0)
        {
            id = 1;
        }
        var gameList = objBs.gameBs.GetByID(id);
        EditGameVM model = new EditGameVM
        {
            gameID = id,
            gameName = gameList.gameName,
            gamePicture = gameList.gamePicture,
            gameRule = gameList.gameRule,
            description = gameList.description
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```