# Updates not reflecting in database from my edit view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I earlier had an issue with my edit view giving errors. This has been resolved from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774770/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-system-data-entity-dynamic?noredirect=1#comment55321325_33774770)

Now I need to make update from my MVC view. Update seem not committed to database as changes are not reflected when I make the update. Below is my update ActionResult:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Update()
    {
        EditGameVM model = new EditGameVM();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(EditGameVM model)
    {
        try { 
            game objGame = new game
            {
                gameID = model.gameID,
                gameName = model.gameName,
                description = model.description,
                gameRule = model.gameRule,
                gamePicture = model.gamePicture.ToString()
            };            
            objBs.gameBs.Update(objGame);
            TempData["Msg"] = "Created Successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("Edit");
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
          ...
        }
    }
```

and here's the corresponding view:

```
@model TeamBuildingCompetition.ViewModels.EditGameVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_new.cshtml";
}
<script>
    tinymce.init({ selector: '#description' });
    tinymce.init({ selector: '#gameRule' });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Game", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <section id="middle">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="center"><h1>Edit Games </h1></div>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.gameID)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gameName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.gameName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gameName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gameRule, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.gameRule, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gameRule, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gamePicture, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.gamePicture, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? and put your gameBs.Update(objGame); method code.

Comment: I don't see where you are calling `SaveChanges()` on the dbcontext

Comment: @DhavalPatel: I didn't get any error. All went fine.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta: There's no exception for this. I didn't add the exception part.

Comment: @user1666620: The SaveChanges() is in my DAL Layer. let me add the update part of the repository pattern.

Comment: @user1666620: You were right after all. I didn't include the Save() method in update method of my repository pattern. Here's my new update method.

public void Update(game g)
        {
            db.Entry(g).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Save();
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I have this code in my BLL, the Save method wasn't included in the Update method of my repository pattern.

namespace BLL
{
    public class GameDB
    {
        private TBCDBEntities db;

```
    public GameDB()
    {
        db = new TBCDBEntities();
    }

    public void Update(game g)
    {
        db.Entry(g).State = EntityState.Modified;            
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

So I included it like this:

```
    public void Update(game g)
    {
        db.Entry(g).State = EntityState.Modified; 
        Save();           
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

And it works like a charm! Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1666620/user1666620